# Psychology Today's Classical IQ test question - abstract line shapes

Tags: visual

I took Psychology Today's Classical IQ test(https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/tests/iq/classical-iq-test) and encountered this question that I wasn't able to solve:
[image]

In fact, this is just the first question of the 57 questions in the test. Although I can just click the <I don't know> button and move on, I would really like to know what is the answer to this problem and the explanation to it. Any help in this problem is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Others have already answered the original question perfectly well; I just felt the need to add that in addition to the many fundamental flaws with IQ tests in general, you should be aware that nor respectable IQ test will be carried out online, and any site attempting to convince you that results from a test like that are worth money are deceptive and border on fraud.

Comment: @Torque "no respectable IQ test will be carried out online". Why not? With the current pandemic situation, and so many people working remotely, almost everything can be done online. Surgeries cannot, but an IQ test certainly does not require access to your body...

Comment: This question is flawed in my opinion. What if someone who is not familiar with the alphabet gets this question? Shouldn't these type of questions be independent from learned things?

Comment: @tgonzaleza Someone unfamiliar with the alphabet wouldn't even be able to read the question, so obviously the test has to assume at least some basic literacy.  Granted this wouldn't work for people who only read/write languages not written in the Roman alphabet.  Different tests presumably exist for such cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those seem to be

> Letters of the English alphabet, rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise-- in this case, it's K, L, M, and N.

So choose

> The middle one, which is a rotated O.

Comment: Rats beat me to it!!

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker yea i kinda expected there to be more than one answerer that was going to be active... in any case i upvoted you as well

Comment: Just curios, I counted lines, 3, 2, 5, 3 and therefore looked at an option with 2 lines, that is 2 or 4. I am not sure how to motivate any of them but if I could come up with a reasonable motivation for any of them, is that inherently wrong?

Comment: @d-b One problem with that solution is that you should reasonably assume that any question has 1 uniquely correct answer.  Since by your criteria, there are 2 equally qualified answers, you can therefore assume that that cannot be the correct criteria.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman But my plan was to find some other common pattern, e.g., that since the L only had straight angels the next "2 line figure" must therefore also only have straight angels = option 4. Could this be considered correct?

Comment: @d-b Sure, but the more complicated you make your criteria, the more likely it is to be not what the designer intended.  Kind of an Occum's Razor situation here.  Also, the intended solution has only one correct value for *each* of the 5 figures in the sequence, not just the answer, which even by your stricter criteria could be any number of possible shapes, not just the 5 options given.  e.g., you could rotate the M to any other angle and your solution would still work, but at the angle given, the intended solution is clearly the simpler, and thus more likely correct, answer.

Answer (score 5):

> It is option number 3 because the image above are the letters KLMN in that order rotated 90deg anticlockwise, option 3 is O turned 90deg anticlockwise. KLMN are consecutive letters of the alphabet leaving O as the next letter.